# IPAddress Control проблема отображения

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

Нашёл на просторах интернета следующий лаконичный код для кастомного контрола для ввода IP адресов. Всё работает замечательно, но есть одно НО. При повторном открытии формы с этим контролом размер формы с содержимым пропорционально увеличивается в 1.5-2 раза.

Артефакт проявляется сразу же при запуске приложения в Debug режиме. В конструкторе текущей формы все контролы увеличиваются и текст становится жирным.

```
public class IPAddressControl : TextBox
{
    private const int WM_NOTIFY = 0x004E,
        WM_USER = 0x0400,
        WM_REFLECT = WM_USER + 0x1C00,
        IPN_FIRST = -860,
        IPM_SETRANGE = (WM_USER + 103),
        IPM_GETADDRESS = (WM_USER + 102),
        IPM_SETADDRESS = (WM_USER + 101),
        IPM_CLEARADDRESS = (WM_USER + 100),
        IPM_ISBLANK = (WM_USER + 105),
        ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES = 0x00000800,
        CS_VREDRAW = 0x0001,
        CS_HREDRAW = 0x0002,
        CS_DBLCLKS = 0x0008,
        CS_GLOBALCLASS = 0x4000,
        WS_CHILD = 0x40000000,
        WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000,
        WS_TABSTOP = 0x00010000,
        WS_EX_RIGHT = 0x00001000,
        WS_EX_LEFT = 0x00000000,
        WS_EX_RTLREADING = 0x00002000,
        WS_EX_LTRREADING = 0x00000000,
        WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR = 0x00004000,
        WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR = 0x00000000,
        WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY = 0x00000004,
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = 0x00000200;

    private int[] values = new int[4];
    bool initialized = false;

    public event FieldChangedHandler FieldChanged;

    public IPAddressControl() : base()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            values[i] = 0;
    }

    [DllImport("comctl32")]
    static extern bool InitCommonControlsEx(ref InitCommonControlsEX lpInitCtrls);

    protected virtual void OnFieldChanged(FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FieldChanged != null) FieldChanged(this, e);
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            if (!initialized)
            {
                InitCommonControlsEX ic = new InitCommonControlsEX();
                ic.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(InitCommonControlsEX));
                ic.Icc = ICC_INTERNET_CLASSES;
                initialized = InitCommonControlsEx(ref ic);
            }
            if (initialized)
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ClassName = "SysIPAddress32";
                cp.Height = 23;
                cp.ClassStyle = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS | CS_GLOBALCLASS;
                cp.Style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | 0x80;
                cp.ExStyle = WS_EX_NOPARENTNOTIFY | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
                if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No
                                                || (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Inherit
                                                && Parent.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.No))
                {
                    cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING | WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR;
                }
                else
                {
                    cp.ExStyle |= WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING | WS_EX_LEFTSCROLLBAR;
                }
                return cp;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.CreateParams;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool SetIPRange(IPField field, byte lowValue, byte highValue)
    {
        if (!initialized) return false;
        Message m = Message.Create(Handle, IPM_SETRANGE, (IntPtr) ((int) field), MakeRange(lowValue, highValue));
        WndProc(ref m);
        return m.Result.ToInt32() > 0;
    }

    public System.Net.IPAddress IPAddress
    {
        get
        {
            if (!initialized) return IPAddress.None;
            return IPAddress.Parse(base.Text);
        }
    }

    public bool IsBlank
    {
        get
        {
            if (!initialized) return !(base.Text.Length > 0);
            Message m = Message.Create(Handle, IPM_ISBLANK, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            WndProc(ref m);
            return m.Result.ToInt32() > 0;
        }
    }

    new public void Clear()
    {
        if (!initialized)
        {
            base.Clear();
            return;
        }
        Message m = Message.Create(Handle, IPM_CLEARADDRESS, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private System.Net.IPAddress GetIpAddress(IntPtr ip)
    {
        if (!initialized) return IPAddress.None;
        return new IPAddress(ip.ToInt64());
    }

    private IntPtr MakeRange(byte low, byte high)
    {
        return (IntPtr) ((int) ((high << 8) + low));
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == (WM_REFLECT + WM_NOTIFY))
        {
            NmIPAddress ipInfo = (NmIPAddress) Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(NmIPAddress));
            if (ipInfo.Hdr.Code == IPN_FIRST)
            {
                if (values[ipInfo.Field] != ipInfo.Value)
                {
                    values[ipInfo.Field] = ipInfo.Value;
                    OnFieldChanged(new FieldChangedEventArgs(ipInfo.Field, ipInfo.Value));
                }
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}

public class FieldChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _field, _value;
    public int Field
    {
        get { return _field; }
    }
    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }
    public FieldChangedEventArgs(int field, int value)
        : base()
    {
        _field = field;
        _value = value;
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Nmhdr
{
    public IntPtr HWndFrom;
    public UIntPtr IdFrom;
    public int Code;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct NmIPAddress
{
    public Nmhdr Hdr;
    public int Field;
    public int Value;
}
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InitCommonControlsEX
{
    public int Size;
    public int Icc;
}

public enum IPField { OctetOne = 0, OctetTwo = 1, OctetThree = 2, OctetFour = 3 }
public delegate void FieldChangedHandler(object sender, FieldChangedEventArgs e);
```

Подскажите как устранить этот артефакт.

P.S. Если в свойствах контрола изменить размер шрифта на больший или меньший и после обратно вернуть 8,25pt то артефакт исчезает.

P.S.S. Также замечено что все GroupBox уменьшены в размерах.

Оригинал кода [здесь](http://www.sanity-free.org/127/an_ipaddress_control_the_win32_sysipaddress32_control_in_csharp.html).

Comment: Это точно WPF ?

Comment: Ошибся с тегом. Исправил.

Comment: Возможно, не относится к проблеме, но в этой строчке: `if (m.Msg == (WM_REFLECT + WM_NOTIFY))` случаем не ошибка? В чем смысл сложения кодов сообщений?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, пробовал закомментировать. Результат не изменился.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в конструктор элемента явно заданный шрифт:

```
public IPAddressControl() : base()
{
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            values[i] = 0;
        this.Font = System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Артефакты с самим контролом пропали. Но вот искажение размеров (в меньшую сторону) других элементов формы остались.

Comment: @Rootware Можно еще попробовать для формы поставить AutoScaleMode = DPI.

Comment: Удалил старую форму и создал новую. Глюки с ресайзом элементов пропали. `AutoScaleMode` пробовал менять - без толку. Возможно, ваш фикс со шрифтом был очень кстати. Т.к. после его добавления шрифты перестали меняться в конструкторе при запуске приложения для отладки. На данный момент всё вроде как работает. Спасибо.